# How can we use tsd reinstall with authentication to install typescript definitions?

Tags: github, typescript

We have a build system on our network that frequently hits the [github api limit](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) for our company's IP address. This, of course, also blocks local developers.

The [readme](https://github.com/Definitelytyped/tsd#readme) indicates that we should be able to authenticate for more requests, but I can't see how.

> The Github API has a 60-requests-per-hour rate-limit for
>   non-authenticated use. You'll likely never hit this as TSD uses local
>   caching and the definition files are downloaded from Github RAW urls.
>   If you need some more then a scope-limited Github OAuth token can be
>   used to boost the limit to 5000.

Comment: You can find the information about authentication on the same page right? Isn't this what you want? https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Comment: I wanted to know where to configure that in the tsd tool. Answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [tsd page on npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/tsd):

#### .tsdrc

This is a optional JSON encoded file to define global settings. TSD looks for it in the  user's home director (eg: `%USERPROFILE%` on Windows, `$HOME` / `~` on Linux), and in the current working directory.

- "**proxy**" - Use a http `proxy`

  Any standard http-proxy as supported by the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) package.

  ```
  {
      "proxy": "http://proxy.example.com:88"
  }
  ```
- "**token**" - Github OAuth token:

  The OAuth token can be used to boost the Github API rate-limit from 60 to 5000 (non-cached) requests per hour. The is token needs just ['read-only access to public information'](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) so no additional OAuth scopes are necessary.

  ```
  {
      "token": "0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0dd47f3c5bc275da8a33"
  }
  ```

You can create this token on Github.com:

1. Go to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new
2. *Deselect* all scopes to create a token with just basic authentication.

   1. (verify you *really* deselected all scopes)
   2. (wonder why these presets were set??)
3. Enter a identifying name, something like "`TSD Turbo 5000`"
4. Create the token.
5. Copy the hex-string to the `token` element in the `.tsdrc` file.
6. Verify enhanced rate-limit using `$ tsd rate`

Change or revoke the token at any time on https://github.com/settings/applications

Note: keep in mind the `.tsdrc` file is *not* secured. Don't use a token with additional scope unless you know what you are doing.

The bare 'no scope' token is *relatively* harmless as it gives 'read-only access to public information', same as any non-autenticated access. But it does *identify* any requests done with it as being *yours*, so it is still *your* responsibility to keep the token private.